# How to make music autoplay and loop in background

Tags: html, loops, audio, autoplay

I am currently using this and the autoplay seems to work but the loop doesn't work.

```
<div id="music"><embed src="Anne_Marie - 2002 [Official Video].mp3" autostart=true loop=true></div>
```

Also, I wanna make it like background music so the play buttons don't show up.

Comment: parameters `autostart=true` and `loop=true` must be wrapped in quotes. like this `autostart="true"` and `loop="true"`

Comment: have a loop at [HTML Background Music Code][1], all HTML attribute assignments should be quoted. 

```
<div id="music"><embed src="Anne_Marie - 2002 [Official Video].mp3" autostart="true" loop="true"></div>
```

  [1]: https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_background_music_codes.cfm

Comment: You are using wrong tag, its not `embed` you are looking for to loop but `audio`.  t hide play pause button dont use `controls` in audio tag/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The loop attribute makes the audio file loop.
- The autoplay attribute makes the file start playing without the user
  needing to play the file.
- The controls attribute shows the controls, omitting it will hide the
  controls.

```
<audio loop autoplay>
    <source src="path/to/file" type="audio/filetype">
</audio>
```

Audio filetype can be: .mp3, .wav, .ogg

Comment: Thx! It worked well, but now how to make it visible?

Comment: @Reosuke1 see my answer, if you add the controls attribute, this will make it visible. 
`<audio loop autoplay controls>`

Comment: won't most browsers block this if user has not interacted with the website ?

Comment: it doesn't work for me... I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

this audio work for me:

```html
<audio autoplay loop src="music/music.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will block autoplay because user has not interacted with website.
It is best to use javascript and make a gameloop and do this:

```js
window.onload = setInterval(GameLoop, 1000 / 10); //10fps

let myAudio = new Audio();

myAudio.src = '/MyFolder/MyFile.mp3';

function Gameloop() {
    myAudio.play();
    if (myAudio.paused == true) {
        myAudio.play();
    }
}
```

The above will play the music whenever it has ended or been paused and will start on user interaction with site.
If you wish to pause your music somewhere or the user to be able to pause it, it is best to use:

```js
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    myAudio.play();
})
```